# Existence of $f'\in F$ such that $f^{[G:F]}=(f')^n$ for finite extension $F\subset G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $F$ be a field and $u\in F$. Further, let $F\subset G$ be a finite extension and $v\in G$ such that $v^n=u$ for $n>0$.

> How would I show that there exists a $\tilde{u}\in F$ such that $u^{[G:F]}=(\tilde{u})^n$?

My first thought was to use the norm map $N_{G/F}(x)=\Pi_{\sigma\in X(G/F)}\sigma(x)$, where $X(G/F)$ is the fundamental set for $F\subset G$. However, I wouldn't know how to continue on this path.

Comment: I think your notation is highly confusing as it is a very widespread standard that $\;f,g\;$ (among other letters)  denote polynomials, and even worse: $\;f'\;$ denotes the derivative of $\;f\;$ (both analytical and formal).

Comment: Also, what is a "fundamental set" in this context?

Comment: @Joanpemo Thanks for the headsup

Comment: @Joanpemo If $A$ is an algebraically closed field that contains $F$, then $X(G/F)=\text{Hom}_F(G,A)$. I hope this is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but let's use another definition of "norm" : let's see $G$ as a finite-dimensional $F$-vector space, and for any $x\in G$ put $L_x:G\to G$ defined by $L_x(a)=xa$, which is a $F$-linear map. Then define $N_{G/F}(x) := \det(L_x)\in F$.

It's easy to see that $N_{G/F}(xy) = N_{G/F}(x)\cdot N_{G/F}(y)$ (because $L_{xy}=L_x\circ L_y$) and $N_{G/F}(x)=x^{[G:F]}$ if $x\in F$ (because then this is the determinant of a homothetic map).

Now if $v^n =u$, then taking the norm $N_{G/F}(v)^n = u^{[G:F]}$. So you may take $\tilde{u}=N_{G/F}(v)$.

---

The notion of norm map you're trying to use doesn't work if $G/F$ is not a separable extension. Let's write $N$ for the norm you define.

If $G/F$ is not separable, then $|X(G/F)|<[G:F]$ so $N(x)\neq x^{[G:F]}$ for $x\in F$, which would be the expected behaviour to make the proof work.

If $G/F$ is separable then you may see [Trace and Norm of a separable extension.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/282966/trace-and-norm-of-a-separable-extension) for a proof that our two definitions of norm coincide.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer! Secondly, is there a way of doing this with 'my' definition of norm?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it should give the same thing if $G/F$ is a separable extension, but I'm not sure about the inseparable case.

Comment: I edited to clarify this point. Last remark : you really shouldn't use $G$ for a field extension, it's an awful notation with huge possibility of confusion with a Galois group. For instance, $K$, $L$ and $E$ are much less confusing.