# Elements of finite field extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I posted this question earlier, and was wondering if somebody could help me answer it:

[Existence of $f'\in F$ such that $f^{[G:F]}=(f')^n$ for finite extension $F\subset G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1714038/existence-of-f-in-f-such-that-fgf-fn-for-finite-extension-f-subs)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I also put a bounty on it if you would like to answer it

Comment: If you put a bounty on your first question, there is no need to post a duplicate, especially when it's only two days old.